# Are there any ways to relate the prime numbers and $\pi$ other than the $\zeta$ function?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, pi

I think it is fascinating that both the primes and $\pi$ show up in the $\zeta$ function. Are there any other ways to relate these two concepts?

Comment: That is a bit vague. Both $\pi$, prime numbers and the Riemann $\zeta$ function are fundamental bricks in the vast fabric of Mathematics, they appear almost everywhere, with a close look.

Comment: Perhaps this will enlighten: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16991/what-are-the-connections-between-pi-and-prime-numbers

Comment: $\zeta(2) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is just a shiny example.

Comment: Related with $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\right)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ being the reason for *two random integers are coprime with probability $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$* (loosely speaking)

Answer (score 1):

One other connection (to which I made a modest contribution) is [Simon Plouffe's algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0303) for computing decimal digits of $\pi$ (see also refinements of this by Bellard and by Gourdon).